# Variable change in integral makes a split domain become conected

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $D=\{(x,y):0<x,0<y,x^2+y^2<4,x^2-y^2>1\}$. Compute $\iint_D(x^5y+xy^5)dA$.

> My attempt:
>
> Let $u=x^2+y^2$,$v=x^2-y^2$.
>
> The Jacobian of the substitution is $J=\frac{-1}{8xy}$.
>
> By using all our information on D, besides $0<x$, we get that our new domain in $uv$ plane is the triangle bounded by $u=v,u=4,v=1$.
>
> > I would like to claim that $0<x$ and $0<y$ $\Rightarrow|J|=\frac{1}{8xy} $ but the fact that $0<x$ does not reflect in the new domain. Furthermore, we may notice that $u=x^2+y^2=(-x)^2+y^2$ and the same goes for $v$. It is as if the two unconected domains $D^*=\{(x,y):0>x,0<y,x^2+y^2<4,x^2-y^2>1\}$ and D, have merged to one domain in $uv$ plane.
> >
> > So what can I do from here? How can I reflect $0<x$ in the new domain, to compute the integral in question?

Alternately, consider the case where we wish to compute $\iint_{D\cup D^*}(x^5y+xy^5)dA$, how can we deal with the fact that $x$ changes signs between the two domains, meaning $J$ changes signs between the two domains?

> I understand the integral may be computed with brute force, using no change of variables, but I am interested to see whether this particular substitution may prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer I was looking for...

The fact that this substitution satisfies $u(x)=u(-x),v(x)=v(-x)$ implies that it is not injective, hence we cannot use it for the split domain $D\cup D^*$. Using it for $D$ only is legal, however, and setting $|J|=\frac{1}{8xy}$ is the indication for that choice.

If we wish to compute the integral over $D\cup D^*$ we need to split the integral over the two domains, and for each, set the correct value of $|J|$. Notice that $f(x,y)=x^5y+y^5x=-f(-x,y)$ thus we get $\iint_Df(x,y)dA=-\iint_{D^*}f(x,y)dA$ which is consistent with the change in the sign of the Jacobian.